# How can I show a string from an array divided by characters and show each character in a different TextView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I have an array of Strings and I want to divide each String by characters and show each character in a different TextView created programatically

```
    val i: Int = 0

    val palabras = arrayOf("Escalera", "Fruta", "Calor", "Automóvil", "Barco", "Sandía", "Aviación", "Fábrica", "Utensilio", "Can", "Perro", "Malabarista", "Hotel", "Juego", "Continente", "Población", "Pirámide", "Átomo", "Molécula", "Agua", "Hidrógeno", "Chimenea", "Polvillo")

    val word = palabras[i]

    val c: Int = 0
    //split word into an array of characters
    val chars = word.toCharArray()

    for (c in chars.indices) {
        //Create TextView
        val textView = TextView(this)
        //Set textView with chars character in the position c
        textView.text = chars[c].toString()
        //Add TextView to constraintLayout
        constraintLayout.addView(textView)

    }
```

I have this piece of code but when I run the app it creates only one TextView, it doesn't create a TextView for each word of the array

Comment: It likely _does_ create multiple, but they're all on top of each other since you haven't specified any constraints.  I'm not sure why you're doing this, but perhaps a LinearLayout would work better?

Comment: Use `ListView` to show each character in each TextView.